# When right clicking on a new form in C# it puts the focus on the mainForm

Tags: c#, forms

In my mainform i have this

```
newForm.Show();
```

I have a treeview in there and when i right click the mainform gets focus and the newForm gets put behind the mainform. I cant really do

```
newForm.Show(mainForm);
or
newForm.ShowDialog(mainForm);
```

since i dont want them to block eachother. Anybody know a fix?

EDIT: Forgot to add this only happens the first time after the first right click it works OK.

Comment: How did you assign the context menu?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé   

    ContextMenuStrip mnu = new ContextMenuStrip();  

    ToolStripMenuItem mnuFind = new ToolStripMenuItem("Search in subtree");  

    ToolStripMenuItem mnuExpand = new ToolStripMenuItem("Expand subtree");

Comment: That is not the assigning but the definition of the menu. Please update the post with a full code sample.

Comment: There was a bug in the RTM version of .NET 4.5 that caused this behavior.  Turn on Windows Update so you'll get the bug fix.